# Use a keyword in namespace? - PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, keyword

I have a theme folder with a theme named default. Now is default also a keyword in PHP.

But the namespacing inside that theme folder should be:

```
Themes\Default\Widgets
```

Is this possible somehow or should I replace default with something else?

Comment: Why you no change the theme name instead?

Comment: Even though this is a duplicate question I think it's better than [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051564/a-php-namespace-called-default). This is one is less specific and would be easier to be found by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051564/a-php-namespace-called-default), default is reserved so you would have to rename it to something else.

Comment: Just found that one. I searched a bit less specific to the problem.